# Drupal 7 - Organic Groups Administrators from Drupal Roles

Tags: drupal-7, roles, administrator, organic-groups

I have a site where we use OG to control access to content. Currently I create all of the groups myself so by default I can add individual users to any group I wish. I have a small team of users who also need to be able to add users to various groups, however the way I understand it, only an administrator of a group can add other users.

Is there a way to say anyone who has the Drupal role Administrator or Manager, is automatically an administrator on every group in the system? Or, can I say anyone who's a member of GROUP A is an admin for all other groups? I've tried the Organic Groups Site Role Assign module, but it didn't seem to do the trick.

Currently, it looks like I have to add each group administrator manually.

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 2):

I think this URL can solve your problem
https://www.drupal.org/node/163567

Answer (score 0):

there are two modules that can do this for you. One is called og_default_members and another one is og_role_override.
Also if you want to hand select which user manages which group, you can go under admin/config/group/roles and add a role like group manager or team manager and then add the user to that group and assign them this role and you can decide what they can or cannot do by setting permissions for them in admin/config/group/permissions.(This is per user)

You can still add this organic role to your organic groups, then use one of the above module and assign this role to a group of users in your site like moderators or administrators. In your case, give them permission to add user.
 This way they do not have administrative power in your group but they do have some authority based on what you see fit.

Personally, I like to create views and use VBO(views_bulk_operations module) so I always know who does what in which group. in terms of people with more authority in a group.

hope this helps.